# Can't creat package.json file after install node

Tags: npm

i can't create package .json file after installing node on my system and setting the path ...
Getting error -4058 and 
This is related to npm not being able to find file

Comment: please tell us more,about your OS what version you had installed and other things

Comment: The  OS is window10 and The version the npm was 6.9.0 and node version was 10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

Check if node and npm is installed correctly

for checking type

npm -v

if no number came then install it properly.

If  any number cam then the npm is installed, then go ahead

Quick fix:-delete package-lock.json and try again

If above does not work, then do below steps

1) delete package-lock.json

2) open task manager and  shut down all nodejs process

3) run npm init or npm install

4) if not works, then restart your system